# Restoring Ubuntu on another device

Tags: grub2, disk-image

I have installed Ubuntu on a Dell PC. Made an image of it with our imaging software.

When I restored the image on another pc. There is only a white cursor blinking, GRUB does not come up.

Is there something like SYSPREP that makes the system ready and shuts it down to make a system independent image?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

Linux uses system dependent UUID's on the disks and in Grub.
This is why my second pc does not boot after the restore.

Step1: Install all needed extra applications like CLAMAV / CLAMTK / LibreOffice / ... on a clean Ubuntu

Step2: Use remastersys to create a backup of your system that can be restored on any kind of system.

```
wget -O - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
apt-get update
apt-get install remastersys
apt-get install remastersys-gui
```

Step3: Start remastersys and select backup. This creates a live boot cd which is saved in `~/custom.iso`

Step4: Install UNetbootin to create a bootable USB stick with this custom image.

Step5: Install a new system with the new USB stick.

Now you have a system independent USB imaging restore stick.

---

Another way is to use FOG.

*FOG is a Linux-based, free and open source computer imaging solution for Windows XP, Vista and 7 that ties together a few open-source tools with a php-based web interface. FOG doesn't use any boot disks, or CDs; everything is done via TFTP and PXE. Also with fog many drivers are built into the kernel, so you don't really need to worry about drivers (unless there isn't a linux kernel driver for it).*

You can just create an image of an Ubuntu system and restore it on any other device. 
No need to wory about UUID's this is all handled by FOG.